# gradients/blurs - How do I reproduce this gradient?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color, gradient, blur

I've been trying to reproduce this art but can't get such smooth blur and how it just "drags" like smoke... Where should I do it: Photoshop or Illustrator. And how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE - please take a quick look around [tour] and [ask] and [answer] a question, to get an idea of our community and the kinds of questions which are appropriate here, and how to frame them in order to encourage the best responses. One thing we like to see is what you've tried so far to achieve your desired results, and where that effort has met trouble. Can you edit to show your current efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Illustrator

Make a circle filled it with a **Radial Gradient**:

- from orange to orange
- from 100% to 0% opacity

and use the **Gradient Annotator** to define the gradient shape:

[image]

With this gradient circle with a **Feather Effect**, add another ellipse with a half radial blur:

[image]

[image: End]